# How do you ping more than once per secound in native CMD?

Tags: cmd, ping

I need to ping more than once per secound for a project, and someone wants a live monitor for amount of time the server is up, and they want high accuracy rate.
This is not for dosing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-i` option to control the interval (in seconds). You can specify sub-second intervals, but note that only a superuser can set the interval to less than 0.2 seconds:

```
$ ping -i 0.5 example.com
```

Comment: What `ping` command is that? The standard Windows `ping` command accepts values from `1` to `255` only for the `-i` option... (note that tag [tag:cmd] relates to Windows...)

Comment: This works on Linux but on windows `-i` is used for specifying the TTL of the packet. I haven't found a solution for Windows so it's probably not possible without starting multiple processes.